# Android bluetooth setpin function

Tags: android, bluetooth

My Android device is trying to connect to a sensor via Bluetooth.

As a normal Bluetooth device, I will need to pragmatically set up the pin code (usually 0000 or 1234)

for the sensor side since it is silent and would not pop up the request dialogue.

I did not find any related clue on the Android dev site.

Does anyone can tell me if there is any approach available to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the PIN, you can call by reflection the hidden method `setPin(byte[])` from the `BluetoothDevice` class.

Example:

```java
try {
  Log.d("setPin()", "Try to set the PIN");
  Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
  m.invoke(device, pin);
  Log.d("setPin()", "Success to add the PIN");
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e("setPin()", e.getMessage());
}
```

Where `device` is your `BluetoothDevice` and `pin` a `byte[]` array which contains the bluetooth device pin.

But I think, you'll prefer to use the method `setPasskey(int)`. It would be easier for you because you want to set a passkey like "0000" or "1234".

[UPDATE]

Previous source links are dead and the class has been updated. Apparently `setPasskey` does not exist anymore. Follow the documentation link below to find the information you need.

Sources: [BluetoothDevice Android documention](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)