# SetPin method of BluetoothDevice always return false

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to pair a BluetoothDevice programmatically without user interaction. So I tried the **setPin()** and the **setPasskey()** methods, but both methods returned false always. For this problem I have taken help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109479/howt-to-connect-two-devices-via-bluetooth-sending-the-pairng-code-by-parameter?rq=1).

The code that I used:

```
private void PairDevice(BluetoothDevice pDevice, String pin)
{
    try
    {   
        Log.d("pairDevice()", "Start Pairing...");

        Method pairMethod = pDevice.getClass().getMethod("setPin", new Class[] {byte[].class});
        Boolean lReturn = (Boolean) pairMethod.invoke(pDevice, pin.getBytes("UTF8"));
        Log.e("pairDevice",""+lReturn);

        if(lReturn.booleanValue())
        {
            Log.d("pairDevice()", "Pairing Finished...");

            Method bondMethod = pDevice.getClass().getMethod("createBond");
            bondMethod.invoke(pDevice);
            Log.d("pairDevice()", "createBond Finished...");
        }           
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("pairDevice()", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to pair with a BluetoothDevice without the need for user interaction?