# Where should we invoke setPin() for bluetooth pairing in android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Where should we insert `setPin(String pin)` for pairing a bluetooth device? should the function be invoked before `createBond` or after ??

Answer in this post [Howt to connect two devices via bluetooth sending the pairng code by parameter? JAVA-Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109479/howt-to-connect-two-devices-via-bluetooth-sending-the-pairng-code-by-parameter?answertab=votes#tab-top) conveys that it should be called before invoking `createBond()`

But the question [How can I avoid or dismiss Android's Bluetooth pairing notification when I am doing programmatic pairing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337032/how-can-i-avoid-or-dismiss-androids-bluetooth-pairing-notification-when-i-am-do) tells the steps in which the bluetooth pairing is done in which the `setPin` is called after `createBond()`. If this works, then it should be invoked inside BroadcastReceiver where we get callback for pairing request.

Which is the right approach? Am really confused !

Answer (score 4):

I found [some test code](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/tests/bluetoothtests/src/android/bluetooth/BluetoothTestUtils.java#174) that seems to suggest you call it after `createBond()` [in response to the `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST` broadcast](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/tests/bluetoothtests/src/android/bluetooth/BluetoothTestUtils.java#1413).